# Indefinite integral functions with vector inputs

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I would sincerely appreciate your help on an integral-related question.

I have two real-valued functions $x(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $y(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and three other functions $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Case 1: I have the following equation
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t)) = g(x(t),y(t))\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt} + h(x(t),y(t))\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}$$
How can I express $f$ in terms of $g$ and $h$?

I initially figured that I could do something like
$$f(x(t),y(t)) = \int_{0}^{x(t)}g(r,y(t))\,dr + \int_{0}^{y(t)}h(x(t),s)\,ds$$
But then I realized I probably didn't correctly handle $dy/dt$ and $dx/dt$ in the first and second terms.

Case 2: In a more general case where $x(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^D, f: \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g: \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^D$, and $$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t)) = \sum_{i=1}^D g_i(x_i(t),x_{-i}(t))\frac{dx_i(t)}{dt}$$
How can I express $f$ in terms of $g$?

Update:

I figured that for Case 1, the following might be correct
$$f(x(t),y(t)) = f(x(0),y(0)) + \int_{0}^{t}g(x(r),y(r)) \frac{d x(r)}{dr} dr + \int_{0}^{t}h(x(s),y(s)) \frac{d y(s)}{ds} ds$$

Then for the more general Case 2, we have
$$
f(x(t)) = f(x(0)) + \int_{0}^t \sum_{i} g_i(x_i(r), x_{-i}(r)) \frac{d x_i(r)}{dr} dr
$$

Please correct my mistakes, thank you.

Comment: Basic, basic correction:  Do not write $\mapsto$ where $\to$ belongs. The syntax $x\mapsto f(x)$ defines a function by its values at each $x$. $f\colon X\to Y$ indicates the domain and codomain of the function.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Some hints:

We cannot play around with the notation and derive from
$$\tag{1}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y) = g(x,y)\frac{dx}{dt} + h(x,y)\frac{dy}{dt}
$$
"something like"
$$\tag{2}
f(x,y) = \int_0^xg(r,y)\,dr + \int_0^yh(x,s)\,ds\,.
$$
I recommend to express in the notation correctly that $x,y$ are functions of $t$
(otherwise the LHS of (1) is zero) and study the tractable example
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y)=f_x(x,y)\,\dot x+f_y(x,y)\,\dot y
$$
that follows simply from the chain rule. In that case we have obviously
$$
g(x,y)=f_x(x,y)\,,\quad h(x,y)=f_y(x,y)
$$
and, quite miraculously, an equation for $f$ that does not involve the function  $h\,:$
$$
f(x,y)=\int_0^x f_x(r,y)\,dr=\int_0^xg(r,y)\,dr\,.
$$
To understand more general cases limit yourself to 2D and study some basic
material about exact, inexact ordinary differential equations or one-forms.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I made some updates to clarify the question. I would also highly appreciate it if you can help me verify my updated information.

Comment: The first equation in Case 1  now makes sense. The obvious one that follows from it is $$f(x(t),y(t))=f(x(0),y(0))+\int_0^t g(x(s),y(s))\dot x(s)\,ds+\int_0^th(x(s),y(s))\dot y(s)\,ds\,.$$

Comment: That's very helpful! So I guess the update for case 2 also works? I never majored in math so thank you for helping me make the question clear.

Comment: Case 2 looks OK.